# Trying to find equal amount of characters in same string

Tags: python, python-3.x, append

I want to see if a string has the same amount of 'x's and 'o's. The method must return a boolean and be case insensitive. The string can contain any chararacter.

Examples input/output:

```
XO("xooxx") => false
XO("ooxXm") => true
XO("zpzpzpp") => true // when no 'x' and 'o' is present should return true
XO("zzoo") => false
```

So I tried to make new lists, and then append for each 'x' and each 'o' but its not quite working. Here is my code so far:

```
def xo(s):
    ex = []
    oh = []
    for letter in s.split():
        if letter.islower() == 'x':
            ex = ex.append(letter)
        elif letter.islower() == 'o':
            oh = oh.append(letter)
    if len(ex) == len(oh):
        return True
    else:
        return False
```

It only returns True on the first ones but not on the last third. It seems to me that the code is not appending properly.

Comment: You should spend some time learning how to debug something like this. Consider adding some things like `print(letter)` to see what is going on (or use a debugger). It's worth you time to figure these things out if you want to learn.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are (at least) three problems in your code:

- `s.split()` splits `s` on every space and returns a list (so assuming you have no spaces, this gives you a list with a single item). Instead, just use `for letter in s:` which iterates over each letter.
- `letter.islower()` checks if the letter is lowercased, returning `True` or `False`. What you want is `letter.lower()` which returns the lowercased version of a character.
- Also (thanks Mark) append doesn't return a value, so when you run `oh = oh.append(letter)` you are assigning a value of `None` to the `oh` variable. You should instead just use `oh.append(letter)` (no assignment).

Comment: Also note: `append()` does not return a value.

Comment: As a suggestion, not directly linked to your problem, instead of adding each letter to a separate list, you'd be better having two variables, both starting with a value of zero, and increment as required.

Comment: Thank you for dissecting that information for me I appreciate it.

Answer (score 2):

Just use `collections.Counter`.

```
>>> from collections import Counter
>>> c = Counter('xooxXo'.lower())
>>> c['x'] == c['o']
True
```

or

```
>>> c = Counter('xooxx'.lower())
>>> c['x'] == c['o']
False
```

Wrap it in your own function if you want to.

Comment: My answer explains what is wrong with the code but this is definitely the best way to solve this.

Comment: @David Meh, I'd say using `str.count' is better.

Comment: Yes I suppose the question is actually more about fixing the OP's code than how to implement the best solution. I'll leave this as a supplementary answer although it probably doesnt deserve a green tick.

Comment: @KellyBundy I like the `Counter` approach because of how general it is. I find that `Counter` can be used in many applications and it's worth getting to know it.

Comment: @David Sure, I like and often use `Counter` myself. But here it's more code and much slower.

Comment: The Counter may be a good solution if you were going to keep the counter and use it for many queries. The count solution is better as a one shot.

Comment: @KellyBundy makes sense, yes. I timed both and `Counter` takes 3x as long as `.count()`.

Comment: @David I guess you tried such short strings? Also try it with long strings (like a million characters).

Comment: Wow! Nice, yes. 1M characters takes about 15x as long. My previous test was only 10.

Comment: Look, efficiency in pathological micro-benchmarks wasn't the goal of this answer. Yes it slower than the count solution. Use the solution that works best for your use case.

Comment: @PaulRooney Hmm, what do you mean with "pathological"?

Comment: 1M length string. Is that not pathological? @Kelly Bundy I dont want to get drawn into any arguments. I conceded its slower, can we leave it at that?

Comment: Yeah, ok. And yes, 1M is unusual. Just suggested that because I'm confident the speed ratio is very close to the limit by then. I don't know how early it gets there, maybe at 1K its already close.

Answer (score 2):

David's answer covers some potential fixes to your code, but if you're looking for something more concise, I would suggest using `.lower()` to lowercase the string upfront, and then use `.count()` to count the number of Xs and Os rather than using a `for` loop:

```py
def xo(s):
    return s.lower().count('x') == s.lower().count('o')
```

This outputs:

```py
False
```

Comment: @PaulRooney [Still a oneliner](https://tio.run/##bcxBCsJADIXhfU6R3SQgXdiNSHsY0UgLdTJkpjg9/Rjc1fqWH7w/bWXS2F@StfaQJ1alzFdAn0lZLWLuFn2LEXd3XWOhUAPjOB5dAwP8bywSKUuh1y3Rz@@EofqTGQc8AySbveUF16/vxaG1Dw) (even shorter :-)

Comment: I guess I need to dive into the count and collections. I keep wanting to use for loops for everything